# How to extract date which is in format as 'May 29 2002'[mm dd yyyy] in Python

Tags: python, regex, date

How to extract date which is in format as 'May 29 2002'[mm dd yyyy] from a chunk of text and store to a different field.

Eg:

> Old:
>
> ```
> id       Description                                       
>  1   A man died on March 22 2002 in an accident..(continues).  
>  2   An employee died while operating lift on May 13 2001..(continues)
> ```
>
> New:
>
> ```
> id       Date
>  1       22-03-2002
>  2       13-05-2001
> ```

I tried various options in python with pandas but is not giving the results in correct format.Kindly help me get a solution.

Thanks
Devi

Answer (score 0):

Try with basic library first.

> Install: pip install parsedatetime

Code:

```
import parsedatetime
p = parsedatetime.Calendar()
parsed_data = p.parse("A man died on March 22 2002 in an accident..(continues)")
day = parsed_data[0].tm_mday
month = parsed_data[0].tm_mon
year = parsed_data[0].tm_year
```

In case of multiple dates I think regex will be quite useful.
Code:

```
 day_pattern : r"(?P<day>(?:[12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9]))(?:th|nd|rd|st)?"
 month_pattern : r"(?P<month>jan(?:uary)?|mar(?:ch)?|may|jul(?:y)?|aug(?:ust)?|oct(?:ober)?|dec(?:ember)?|sep(?:tember|t)?|apr(?:il)?|jun(?:e)?|nov(?:ember)?|feb(?:ruary)?)",
 year_pattern : r"(?P<year>(?:19|20)?\d\d)",
 mm_pattern : r"(?P<month>(?:0?[1-9]|1[012]))",
 dd_pattern : r"(?P<day>(?:[12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9]))",
 yy_pattern : r"(?P<year>(?:19|20)?\d\d)",
```

You need to check position of each match and depending on those you can decide the multiple dates.

Comment: ..thank you so much for the answer ..just a doubt will it identify if two dates are given in the text?i find it takes only the latest date

Comment: Updated the answer. Regex will give you better matchs.

Answer (score 0):

use strptime from python datetime.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('May 29 2002', "%B %d %Y")
```

This will return a datetime object.

If you want a date object, you can try the following code:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('May 29 2002', "%B %d %Y").date()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior